# Fast login form on the right side in magento

Tags: magento

I want to add same login form in my site

is there any module available for that or we can have something else coding changes for this
please suggest me something

i want something like this : 
http://livedemo00.template-help.com/magento_42632/

Answer (score 1):

You could create a block of type customer/form_login. Using the XML as follows

```
<block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_small_login" template="customer/form/small-login.phtml" />
```

You can view the `customer/form/login.phtml` form for reference of what kind of fields your block is expecting.0

You can then add this to your sidebar using

`<?php $this->getChildHtml('customer_small_login'); ?>`

**NOTE:** Ensure your adding you XML block as a child node of the sidebar which you wish to include it in.

Comment: thanks for reply. But hv you visited the http://livedemo00.template-help.com/magento_42632/ link? i want the login form same as in the given template...